# trying to change nodes in xslt following method seen on stackoverflow

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning XSLT. I am trying to turn the  nodes into  nodes following @Rich's advice this post [How to replace a node-name with another in Xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928377/how-to-replace-a-node-name-with-another-in-xslt)

Here is my input XML:

```
<ns:positionSkillResponse xmlns:ns="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com">
<ns:return>1</ns:return>
<ns:return>9</ns:return>
</ns:positionSkillResponse>
```

I am trying to transform it with the code below, which is causing a parser error. I think the ns:return is the issue because it the transformer code does not know how to resolve the namespace, ns. But the namespace is not published to a URL, so I can't just point it there. Is that the problem? What do I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="ns:return">
    <parameter>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </parameter>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
Error:XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [<a href='xsltprocessor.transformtoxml'>xsltprocessor.transformtoxml</a>]: No stylesheet associated to this object
```

[Testing via this tool:](http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSL is invalid (it has an unfinished namespace declaration and is missing a closing `xsl:stylesheet` tag), but even when this is fixed, that tool doesn't seem to work. Try this one instead:

http://www.xslfiddle.net/

When this XSLT is used in that tool with your given input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="ns:return">
    <parameter>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </parameter>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result produced is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ns:positionSkillResponse xmlns:ns="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com"><parameter>1</parameter><parameter>9</parameter></ns:positionSkillResponse>
```