# Transform complex and variable xml

Tags: php, xml

I've a complex XML that I want to transform in HTML. Some tags need to be replaced in html tags.

The XML is this:

```
<root>
<div>
    <p>
        <em>bol text</em>, some normale text
    </p>
</div>
<list>
    <listitem>
        normal text inside list <em>bold inside list</em>
    </listitem>
    <listitem>
        another text in list...
    </listitem>
</list>
<p>
    A sample paragraph
</p>
```

The text inside the  element is variable, which means that the other xml that I parse can completely change.

The output I want is this (for this scenario):

```
<root>
    <div>
        <p>
            <strong>bol text</strong>, some normale text
        </p>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            normal text inside list <strong>bold inside list</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
            another text in list...
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        A sample paragraph
    </p>
</root>
```

I make a recursive function for parse any single node of xml and replace it in HTML tag (but doesn't work):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->load('section.xml');
echo $doc->saveHTML();

function printHtml(DOMNode $node)
{
    if ($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
        {
            printHtml($child);
        }
    }

    if ($node->nodeName == 'em')
    {
        $newNode = $node->ownerDocument->createElement('strong', $node->nodeValue);
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
    }

    if ($node->nodeName == 'listitem')
    {
        $newNode = $node->ownerDocument->createElement('li', $node->nodeValue);
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

This is an example of a complete xml:

```
<root>
    <div>
        <p>
            <em>bol text</em>, some normale text
        </p>
    </div>
    <list>
        <listitem>
            normal text inside list <em>bold inside list</em>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            another text in list...
        </listitem>
    </list>
    <media>
        <info isVisible="false">
            <title>
                <p>Image title <em>in bold</em> not in bold</p>
            </title>
        </info>
        <file isVisible="true">
            <href>
                "path/to/file.jpg"
            </href>
        </file>
    </media>
    <p>
        A sample paragraph
    </p>
</root>
```

Which has to be transformed into:

```
<root>
    <div>
        <p>
            <strong>bol text</strong>, some normale text
        </p>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            normal text inside list <em>bold inside list</em>
        </li>
        <li>
            another text in list...
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- the media tag can be presented in two mode: with title visible, and title hidden -->
    <!-- this is the case when the title is hidden -->
    <img src="path/to/file.jpg" />
    
    <!-- this is the case when the title is visible -->
    <!-- the info tag (inside media tag) has an attribute isVisible="false" which means it doesn't have to be shown. -->
    <!-- if the info tag has visible=true, the media tag must be translated into
     <div>
        <img src="path/to/file.jpg" />
        <p>Image title <strong>in bold</strong> not in bold</p>
     <div>
     -->
    <p>
        A sample paragraph
    </p>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a language specially designed for this task: it's called XSLT, and you can easily express your desired transformation in XSLT and invoke it from your PHP program. There's a learning curve, of course, but it's a much better solution than writing low-level DOM code.

In XSLT you write a set of template rules saying how individual elements should be handled. Many elements in your example are copied through unchanged, so you can start with a default rule that does this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The "match" part says what part of the input you are matching; the body of the rule says what output to produce. The xsl:apply-templates does a recursive descent to process the children of the current element.

Some of your elements are simply renamed, for example

```
<xsl:template match="listitem">
 <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Some of the rules are a little bit more complex, but still easily expressed:

```
<xsl:tempate match="media/file[@isVisible='true']">
  <img src="{href}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope you agree that this declarative rule-based approach is much clearer than your procedural code; it's also much easier for someone else to change the rules in six months' time.

Comment: But the media element is translated into:
<media>
        <info>
            <title>
                <p>Image title <strong>in bold</strong> not in bold</p>
            </title>
        </info>
        <img src="&#10;                &quot;path/to/file.jpg&quot;&#10;            "/>
    </media>

The <media> tag remains in the output instead of be replaced by the <img> tag...

Tanks so much in every case!

Comment: Ok, I've try with this code...I'm very poor with XSLT... :)
    <xsl:template match="media[@isVisible and @isVisible='true']">
        <xsl:if test="info[@isVisible and @isVisible='true']">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="info/title"/></p>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="href" select="translate(translate(translate(file/href, '&quot;', ''), ' ', ''), '&#10;', '')"/>
        <img src=" {$href}"/>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: You need to add an extra rule for the media element `<xsl:template match="media"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` which causes it to process the children without outputting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe, it's not the most correct idea, but why not just to use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)? That way You will see clearly the list of changes to apply and add / remove new ones easily.

1. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) `$file = file_get_contents('file.xml');`
2. [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) `$file = str_replace("<em>", "<strong>", $file);`
3. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) `file_put_contents('file.html', $file);`

**UPDATE** (Some more ideas regarding the changes in the question)

This seems a little bit tricky (at least for me now) to use PHP + DOM here. Maybe, it would be more reasonable to use XSL / XSLT  (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations). In that case, smth. similar can be found here: [How to replace a node-name with another in Xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1928377/2510628)

XSLT specifically used for Language **Transformations** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: Hi, tanks for your reply. Thi solution can be done for thi scenario, but I have other tags, like <media> wich is more complex like the <em>. For sample: <media><title>Image one</title><file href="../path/to/file.jpg"/></media> wich must be translated in <img src="" /> tag. This transformation with str_replace() is very difficult... any other ideas? Tanks!