# Find inline anchor tags and modify them in PHP

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am parsing web pages by url to turn them mobile friendly. I'm modifying each ,  tag class to turn them into block (width:100%) buttons so they are become better to click on mobile devices. The problem is that some of the links are inside text:

```
<div>some random text <a> some other random text <a> and some more text </div>
```

Is there a way to extract those inline links from others and give them any other class.

**My idea how to do it would be:**

-links that are surrounded by n number of words and are children of the same container element.

Some links may be surrounded by strong, span etc tags that should not be considered as containers.

Do you guys have any other ideas how to make it work?

Best,
Martti

Comment: Stop using that simple_html_dom library, use `DOMXPath` and `DOM`. They are both part of the PHP core. To the topic, it's hard to say and I guess there is no 100% safe way because even an inline link can be at the end of a sentence for example and so on. You need to play around with it and find a compromise that fits your input data

Comment: Why should I avoid simple_html_dom? Is there a speed difference? I find simple_html_dom easy to use. To the main topic... Yes, I am aware that the link may be at the start/end of the container. But I thought you may have some ideas to give it a try. The code should calculate if there are for example 3 words either one or the other end of the tag.

Comment: simple_html_dom is written in php, while the php core is written in C. I expect significant performance differences, but never tested it. More important (imo) is the fact that `xpath` and `DOM` are well defined standards.

Comment: Check [`PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) !

Comment: I have used simple dom for years and got used to it. As you are saying native is faster I am planning on switching to native as I have only  small number of queries to replace. But it does not help me with my main topic :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try wi XSLT. In this thread I think you can find sometings helpful: [Transform complex and variable xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650289/transform-complex-and-variable-xml)

Hope this helpfull...

Comment: XSLT has its limitations. Counting words in sibling text nodes for example.