# Dynamically change Element Names XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to alter an xml file using xslt. The requirements are that I should reduce the structure down to a single node that contains a list of elements taken from the xml, with some elements changing name.

I have managed to get the xslt to return only the fields that I want to return, but I have no idea how to alter the structure of the resultant xml so that all the fields are listed in a single element at `<Item>` Level. Here is some example xml:

```
<MyData>
<BigGroups>
  <BigGroup>
    <Id>100</Id>
    <LittleGroups>
      <LittleGroup>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Items>
          <Item>
            <ItemId>1</ItemId>
            <Foo>
              <This>Here This is</This>
              <That>That is here</That>
            </Foo>
            <Bar>
              <Camp>
                <Another>Look Another one</Another>
              </Camp>
              <More>Oh god; more</More>
            </Bar>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <ItemId>2</ItemId>
            <Foo>
              <This>Here This is</This>
              <That>That is here</That>
            </Foo>
            <Bar>
              <Camp>
                <Another>Look Another one</Another>
              </Camp>
              <More>Oh god; more</More>
            </Bar>
          </Item>
        </Items>
      </LittleGroup>
      <Id>20</Id>
      <!--Items, Item, Foo, Bar etc-->
    </LittleGroups>
    <!--More Little Groups maybe-->
  </BigGroup>
</BigGroups>
</MyData>
```

I have the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:Translate="my:Translate">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <Translate:Fields>
    <Field>
      <OldName>This</OldName>
      <NewName>NEW_This</NewName>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <OldName>ItemId</OldName>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <OldName>Another</OldName>
    </Field>
  </Translate:Fields>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/Translate:Fields/Field/OldName])]">
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That keeps only the fields I want, but now I need to convert the output to essentially countain one group of elements per item, with all child elements in the same level - to  look like this:

```
<MyData>
  <Item>
    <ItemId>1</ItemId>
    <NEW_This>Here This is</NEW_This>
    <Another>Look Another one</Another>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemId>2</ItemId>
    <NEW_This>Here This is</NEW_This>
    <Another>Look Another one</Another>
  </Item>
</MyData>
```

I am completely at a loss as to how can I change the structure so all fields are in a single element, grouped in this case by Item. Looking around, all the example cases about renaming elements seem to assume that you can hard code the old and new names into the xslt (like this one [How to replace a node-name with another in Xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928377/how-to-replace-a-node-name-with-another-in-xslt)), but I specifically need to use a list of old and new field names as in the example above.

I can use the translate to look up which fields to include after much searching, but I cannot seem to update the elements with `<NewName>` values (I've been using `xsl:element name=` type bits, but it always seems to add new fields, not replace names. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSL 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- keep these -->
<xsl:template match="MyData | Item | ItemId | Another">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename this -->
<xsl:template match="This">
    <NEW_This>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </NEW_This>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress other leaf nodes -->
<xsl:template match="*[text()]" priority="0"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. The difficulty I have here is the requirement to hard code the old and new names into the xslt in order to rename the fields; I would really like to use a schema like the Translate one in my example which I use to choose which fields to include and new names where relevant.

Comment: Just to clarify, the question was asking partly how to dynamically rename the included nodes by using a list of old and new names (as exemplified by the Translate:Fields schema above); there are other cases like the one linked in the question which explain how to rename a single node, mostly using the same method you mention - is there a way to convert that to build from a list?